# Get gmail User's contacts

Tags: android, gmail, contacts

Hi i'm making an app which need to get user's gmail account contact list.. I have searched the net but I didn't really find anything helpful. I dont know from where to start. Please Advice

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: did you get solution for this? I need to implement the same. Can you help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

These links may be of assistance to you:

- http://blog.doityourselfandroid.com/2010/11/10/oauth-flow-in-android-app/
- https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BztL1R2scjctYmYwYjM2MmQtNGNlZC00MzNmLTllYzUtZjg4YWFkODU3ZWMw/edit?pli=1#
- http://androidwarzone.blogspot.in/2011/07/android-oauth-full-example-with-source.html

Answer (score 0):

A simple Google search for "google contact apis" turns up their full documentation.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Beyond that you might need to figure out how to do simple web requests from within your application, this should be very well documented.

Comment: Well Sir thank you for your response. I have seen this.. I didn't say that i found nothing at all while searching for it.. I said i coudln;t find anything usefull Since i'm newbie to android development and i have not worked with the Oauth system

Comment: @Kevin.. I have tired a tutorial for google contact api but it has a problem that i cant figure out.. Its retrieves the request token but is unable to retrieve my contacts from my contact list..